# calling methods in object oriented php

Tags: php, oop

I'm sure this will look like stupid question for most of you. However, I've been banging my head for quite a while over it.
Coming from ASP.NET/C#, I'm trying to use PHP now. But the whole OOrintation gives me hard time.

I have the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

echo "hello<br/>";

class clsA
{
    function a_func()
    {
        echo "a_func() executed <br/>";
    }
}

abstract class clsB
{
    protected $A;
    
    function clsB()
    {
        $A = new clsA();
        echo "clsB constructor ended<br/>";
    }
} 


class clsC extends clsB
{

    function try_this()
    {
        echo "entered try_this() function <br/>";
        $this->A->a_func();
    }
}

$c = new clsC();

$c->try_this();

echo "end successfuly<br/>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

To my simple understanding this code should result with the following lines:

> hello
>
> clsB constructor ended
>
> entered try_this() function
>
> a_func() executed

however, it does not run 'a_func', all I get is:

> hello
>
> clsB constructor ended
>
> entered try_this() function

Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem lies here:

```
$A = new clsA();
```

Here, you're assigning a new `clsA` object to the **local variable** `$A`.  What you meant to do was assign it to the **property** `$A`:

```
$this->A = new clsA();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer but also you could extend the b class to the a class this way you can access the a class in C, like below:

```
  <?php 

  echo "hello<br/>";

  class clsA{
      function a_func(){
          echo "a_func() executed <br/>";
      }
  }

  abstract class clsB extends clsA{
      function clsB(){
          echo "clsB constructor ended<br/>";
      }
  } 


  class clsC extends clsB{
      function try_this(){
          echo "entered try_this() function <br/>";
        self::a_func();
      }
  }

  $c = new clsC();

  $c->try_this();

  echo "end successfuly<br/>";
  ?>
```

Comment: In this case, he `could` but nobody knows if it's what he wants to do, as perhaps class A has nothing to do with B and C in hierarchical structure :)

Comment: @Alexandrew true, but just giving it s an answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, that what I meant. I knew it had to do with something silly like that. It worked. Thanks a million.